# How to attach a template to many .docx files using PowerShell?

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

I have been trying to update a number of document templates. I have tried a few different methods, but this is the most recent code I have been working with.

The "$word.quit()" has been causing a "Unable to cast COM object..." error

I am not sure what's wrong with it.

```
    $word=New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $updated = 0
    $template = "C:\User\test.dotx"
    Get-childItem -Path "C:\User\test" -Recurse -Filter *.docx |
        Foreach-Object {
        $document = $Word.Documents.Open($WordFile.FullName)
            $word.documents.add($template)
        $document.saveas($_, $wdFormatDocument)
        $document.Close()
            }
    $word.quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
    Remove-Variable word
    Write-Host $updated "Files Changed"
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the template of an existing `Document` object, use :

```
documentObject.AttachedTemplate = "[FULL PATH TO TEMPLATE FILE]"
```

For more information see Microsoft's
[Document.AttachedTemplate property (Word)](https://docs.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/vba/api/word.document.attachedtemplate).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, this didn't help me at all.